# Is there a way to use the previous calculated row value with the sum of a different column in a Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
                     A          B
2021-05-19 07:00:00  Nan        Nan
2021-05-19 07:30:00  0.00       Nan
2021-05-19 08:00:00  0.00       Nan
2021-05-19 08:30:00  0.00       Nan
2021-05-19 09:00:00  19.91      Nan
2021-05-19 09:30:00  0.11       Nan
2021-05-19 10:00:00  0.00       Nan
2021-05-19 10:30:00  22.99      Nan
2021-05-19 11:00:00  0.00       Nan
```

Require:

```
                     A          B
2021-05-19 07:00:00  Nan        0.00
2021-05-19 07:30:00  0.00       0.00
2021-05-19 08:00:00  0.00       0.00
2021-05-19 08:30:00  0.00       0.00
2021-05-19 09:00:00  19.91      3.32
2021-05-19 09:30:00  0.11       2.78
2021-05-19 10:00:00  0.00       2.32
2021-05-19 10:30:00  22.99      5.76
2021-05-19 11:00:00  0.00       4.80
```

Calculation for column B:

```
B1 = A1
B2 = ((B1*5)+A2)/6
B3 = ((B2*5)+A3)/6
B4 = ((B3*5)+A4)/6
etc.
```

I have already attempted a calculation in Python with the shift function but this doesn't work, would be great if someone can help me in the right direction.

Comment: You cant really use `shift` as the very next value depends on the calculation of previous value and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can define a function `fast_sum` to perform the required calculation then using the technique called just in time compilation, compile this function to machine code so that it can run more efficiently at `C` like speeds

```
import numba

@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def fast_sum(a):
    b = np.zeros_like(a)
    b[0] = a[0]
    for i in range(1, len(a)):
        b[i] = (b[i - 1] * 5 + a[i]) / 6 
    return b

df['B'] = fast_sum(df['A'].fillna(0).to_numpy())
```

---

```
                         A         B
2021-05-19 07:00:00   0.00  0.000000
2021-05-19 07:30:00   0.00  0.000000
2021-05-19 08:00:00   0.00  0.000000
2021-05-19 08:30:00   0.00  0.000000
2021-05-19 09:00:00  19.91  3.318333
2021-05-19 09:30:00   0.11  2.783611
2021-05-19 10:00:00   0.00  2.319676
2021-05-19 10:30:00  22.99  5.764730
2021-05-19 11:00:00   0.00  4.803942
```

Performance test on sample dataframe with `90000` rows

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)

%%timeit
df['B'] = fast_sum(df['A'].fillna(0).to_numpy())
# 1.62 ms ± 93.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through the DataFrame and set column `B` as each value of `B` depends on its own previous value.

```
for i, date in enumerate(df.index):
    if i==0:
        df.at[date, "B"] = 0
    else:
        df.at[date, "B"] = (df["B"].iat[i-1]*5+df.at[date, "A"])/6
df
>>
                         A         B
2021-05-19 07:00:00   0.00  0.000000
2021-05-19 07:30:00   0.00  0.000000
2021-05-19 08:00:00   0.00  0.000000
2021-05-19 08:30:00   0.00  0.000000
2021-05-19 09:00:00  19.91  3.318333
2021-05-19 09:30:00   0.11  2.783611
2021-05-19 10:00:00   0.00  2.319676
2021-05-19 10:30:00  22.99  5.764730
2021-05-19 11:00:00   0.00  4.803942
```

Comment: Clearly looping will take time and is not efficient.

Comment: Yes but each value of the column depends on its own previous value, so I don't see a way to implement `shift`. Please feel free to provide a more efficient answer.

Comment: This gave me the following error:   
 `File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 96, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.set_value
 File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.set_value
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 595, in pandas._libs.index.convert_scalar
ValueError: Cannot assign nan to integer series`

Comment: Can you check the output of `df.dtypes`? Or just add the line `df = df.astype('float64')` before my code.

Comment: Even I can't find any efficient way better than looping one. Can't be solved using shift and cumsum :/. This looks okay to me.

Comment: df.dtypes gives:
`A   float64
B    int64`

Comment: Just add the line `df = df.astype('float64')` before my code.

Answer (score 2):

With some math, we can turn this recursive formula to a geometric-series like one:

```
df["B"] = (df.A
             .fillna(0)
             .expanding()
             .apply(lambda s: (1/6)*(s * ((5/6) ** np.arange(len(s))[::-1])).sum() + (5/6)**s.size*s.iloc[0]))
```

It amounts to

```
N := window.size

B_j = (5/6)^(N-1) A_1 + (1/6) \sum_{j=2}^{N} (5/6)^(N-j) A_j
```

where window is [`expanding`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.expanding.html) and corresponds to `s` in the code. In the code, however, we sum the `A_1` together with others & thereby take `1/6` of it; so we add the remaining `5/6` of it, hence the `(5/6)^N` (rather than `N-1`) in front of it; output is equivalent. We also turn `NaN`s in `A` to 0 to prevent them from propagating.

to get

```
                         A         B
2021-05-19 07:00:00    NaN  0.000000
2021-05-19 07:30:00   0.00  0.000000
2021-05-19 08:00:00   0.00  0.000000
2021-05-19 08:30:00   0.00  0.000000
2021-05-19 09:00:00  19.91  3.318333
2021-05-19 09:30:00   0.11  2.783611
2021-05-19 10:00:00   0.00  2.319676
2021-05-19 10:30:00  22.99  5.764730
2021-05-19 11:00:00   0.00  4.803942
```

Comment: Is this the end to the question then ;)

Comment: @AnuragDhadse What do you mean `:)`?

Comment: @Tenzin Accept this answer if it works otherwise we spent another hour of our precious life.

Comment: df["B"] = (df.A.expanding().apply(lambda s: (s * ((5/6) ** np.arange(len(s))[::-1])).sum()/6 + (5/6)**s.size*s.iloc[0])) Gives:
NameError: name 'np' is not defined

Comment: @Tenzin `import numpy as np`

Comment: @Tenzin Yes, in the first version of the question you shared there was no `NaN` but it is added I see. To fix that, you can fill the `NaN`s with 0 beforehand: `df.A = df.A.fillna(0)` and then the above code.

Comment: ...or take the expanding windows over NaN-filled `A` to keep `A` unchanged; edited so.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to express the function

```
B[i] = (A[i-1] * 5 + A[i])/6
```

You are on the right track with shift

```py
B = ((A.shift(1)*5)+A)/6
B.iat[0] = A.iat[0]
```

However, if you want to express the recursive function

```
B[i] = (B[i-1] * 5 + A[i])/6
```

Then you cannot use vectorized pandas operations and can just calculate this using normal Python code, as another answer points out.

Comment: Shouldn't the shift should be `A.shift(-1)`.

Comment: B2 is a function of B1 and A2, not A1 and A2.

Comment: No, `shift(1)` shifts all of the values forward. So the first element of `A.shift(1)` is `nan` and the second element is `A[0]`

Comment: But checking the computation he wrote it looks the shift should be backward.

Comment: This did not work as expected, just tried: `df["B"] = ((df["B"].shift(1)*5)+df["A"])/6`.

B2 should take the previous B1 value in the calculation.